# Grab the UL data-value on A jQUERY li grab

Tags: jquery, html, css

How would i go about grabbing the UL assigned data-value of a li grab. Il show you the code . I wish to grab the top UL data value along with the LI value, I have the Jquery set up to grab the LI value but im stuck grabbing the UL value at the same time. im a little unsure as to the syntax of jquery so im struggling to do it correctly...

Many thanks in advance.

```
<form class="searchwrapper" id='searchformmain' action="linkdsearchpagination.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >

<input type="text" id="searchfor" name="searchfor" placeholder="What Are you Looking for?" class="textsearchmain" >


<button name="submitted" type="submitmain" action="submit" target='linkdsearchpagination.php' class="searchbuttonmain" >Search</button> 

</form>


        <div id="ggg" class="col">
        <h4 class="ban">Temp jobs</h4>
        <div class="cats">

            <ul id="tempjobs" data-value='temp jobs' class="left">


                    <li><strong>Creative</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="tv film video">tv / film / video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="crew">crew</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="talent">talent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="event">event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="labour">labour</a></li>

                <br>

                    <li><strong>Computer</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="internet engineers">internet engineers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="web info design">web/info design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="writing editing">writing / editing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="admin office">admin / office</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="art media design">art / media / design</a></li>


                <br>


                    <li><a href="" data-value="security"><strong>Security</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="business">business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="public">public</a><li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="domestic">domestic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="personal">personal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="transport">transport</a></li>


                <br>


                    <li><strong>Skilled trade / craft</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="education">education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="architech egineering">arch / engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="legal paralaegal">legal / paralegal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="business management">business / mgmt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="accounting finance">accounting+finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-value="customer service">customer services</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
        </div>












</div> <!----central column-------->


</div><!------WRAP-------->





</body>

</html>

<!---get list value and post to form--->
<script>

$("#jobs a,#tempjobs a,#community a,#dating a,#services a,#housing a,#forsale a").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$("#searchfor").val($(this).data('value'));

var data2=(this ul).data('value');

$("#catagorymain").val($(this).data2('value'));// IV GOT ISSUE WITH THIS

//$("#searchformmain").submit(); 
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="searchwrapper" id='searchformmain' action="linkdsearchpagination.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >

<input type="text" id="searchfor" name="searchfor" placeholder="What Are you Looking for?" class="textsearchmain" >


<button name="submitted" type="submitmain" action="submit" target='linkdsearchpagination.php' class="searchbuttonmain" >Search</button> 

</form>



    <div id="ggg" class="col">
        <h4 class="ban">Temp jobs</h4>
        <div class="cats">

            <ul id="tempjobs" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' class="left">


                    <li><strong>Creative</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="tv film video">tv / film / video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="crew">crew</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="talent">talent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="event">event</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="labour">labour</a></li>

                <br>

                    <li><strong>Computer</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="internet engineers">internet engineers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="web info design">web/info design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="writing editing">writing / editing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="admin office">admin / office</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="art media design">art / media / design</a></li>


                <br>


                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="security"><strong>Security</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="business">business</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="public">public</a><li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="domestic">domestic</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="personal">personal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="transport">transport</a></li>


                <br>


                    <li><strong>Skilled trade / craft</strong></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="education">education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="architech egineering">arch / engineering</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="legal paralaegal">legal / paralegal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="business management">business / mgmt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="accounting finance">accounting+finance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-loc-subject='temp jobs' data-value="customer service">customer services</a></li>


            </ul>

        </div>
        </div>





</div> <!-----jobs--->








</div> <!----central column-------->


</div><!------WRAP-------->





</body>

</html>

<!---get list value and post to form--->
<script>
$("#jobs a,#tempjobs a,#community a,#dating a,#services a,#housing a,#forsale a").on("click", 
function(e) {e.preventDefault(); //prevent auto submitting the form

             $("#searchfor").val($(this).data('value'));   //get # id=searchfor input .value to this.data.value

             $("#catagorymain").val($(this).data('loc-subject')); //get # id=catagorymain .value to = this.data.value

            });
</script>
```

Simple added a data-loc-subject to every LI and grabbed it with the jquery by changing the .data('value') to data('loc-subject')

works fine..